# How to prevent counting an empty NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I would like to simulate the SMS Bubbles of the iPhone for my own app. I found some nice code overhere (FYI): http://vimeo.com/8718829 . It is a restyled UITableView. Exactly what a wanted.

Here is the problem:
- The Tableview is filled with an array of messages
- It needs to be a NSMutable array because you want to add messages on the fly. 
- When there are no messages yet, the message-array is empty. 
- But counting an empty NSMutableArray causes an exeception, the app crashes. (you need the count for scrolling).

So what is a nice solution for that? I now pre fill the array with "". But that is very ugly. You see a mini bubble on the screen.

Can you hide cells? In the example on the video, there are already 2 messages so the problem does no occur.

Any suggestion is welcome. Tnx
Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually counting an empty array does not raise any exception. I think the problem is here:

```
- (void)add {
    if(![field.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [messages addObject:field.text];
        [tbl reloadData];
        NSUInteger index = [messages count] - 1;
        [tbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

        field.text = @"";
    }
}
```

As the "-1" index cannot exist. You can edit that line to

```
        NSUInteger index = MAX(0, [messages count] - 1);
```

And it should work.

Comment: Yeah, writing it down had some therapeutic effect on me. I added a NSInteger as counter. That whould add up each time a message is added. That worked.

Comment: But I guess the answer of Michele is right as well. It had indeed something to do with that line. And I wish I would have known that solution earlier. So thank you for providing it. (I thought I read that an NSArray could be counted 0, but not an NSMutableArray. Apparently i am wrong. Sry.)

Answer (score 1):

You can count an empty array (I assume you mean [arrayName count]) as long as its alloc'd so make sure its initialized somewhere earlier.